# Tastypie, Django, joining unrelated resources

Tags: django, join, tastypie

My question is how do i join unrelated resources that have a similar variable
Both resources have an 8 length VARCHAR variable, both named code.
Due to how to data is constructed I cannot make any assumption that would lead to this being a foreign key relation but I do however need to join this two tables together if they have similar code values, how do I join these resources together to be displayed in tastypie/django?

```
    class CodeDescription(models.Model):
        code = models.CharField(db_column='Code', max_length=10)
        description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=255)
    class TechnicalDif(models.Model):
        code = models.CharField(db_column='Code', max_length=10)
```

As you can see these tables hold the same sort of value but CodeDescription holds the details of what the code means, but doesn't necessarily have the definition for all the codes, so a foreignkey relation cannot be applied, How would i join these two tables for display using them as a tastypie resource?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think you can do this is programatically in the dehydrate method of the relevant TastyPie ResourceClass. So for each loaded object you could do a query and set an appropriate value in the bundle.

Alternatively, I suppose you could create a join table, that joins related CodeDescriptions to TechnicalDifs, and populate it programatically with a query that you run over the tables intermittently (e.g. when something changes).

Comment: Do you know where i can get more info on the first option, the alternative is not reasonable as there are over 4 million records that i am dealing with

Comment: Well the documentation is in TastyPie's doco about the ResourceClass and the dehydrate method, plus the Django doco for the Django models. I'd actually suggest for a huge volume of data, the "real time" programatic join is far more problematic than an off-line batch process. The batch process is a once-off, then all you need to do is detect changes, either with a SQL Trigger or in your program logic. Whereas a real-time programmatic join may be expensive every time you get a request. You'll have to assess that yourself.

Comment: Can you use a no SQL database, e.g. Hadoop?

Comment: As it turns out this is not a necessary requirement, but I will look into these answers for future reference